# How to test the Mail using assertions in laravel without Mailable class

Tags: php, laravel

```
Mail::send([], [], function ($message) use ($body) {
    $message->to('foo@example.com');
    $message->subject('Sample test');
    $message->setBody($body, 'text/html');
});
```

How can I test the below code without using Mailable?

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You can mock facades, it is very hard to assert that the closure does the correct operations.

```
Mail::shouldReceive('send')
    ->once();
```